# Do not show any location tracking alert on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

my app track location of user (CLLocationManager). i do not want to default alert to appear '"..Would Like to Use Your Current Location"', is it possible.

if location service is enable app should track the user location and if disable should not. but while tracking not to show any alert message which appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `+[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` to determine whether the user has allowed permission. This should not trigger the popup, but of course it is just always going to return `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` until you do decide to trigger the popup.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Comment: is there any other way to get the current location… where i won't have  pop up like other library or some thing…

Comment: No, why would Apple force an auth popup for one method of getting location but not some other method?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. When you start for the location tracking, it will definitely ask. According to apple guideline, you can not track the user with out his knowledge. So, you cant do it.

Comment: ok, thank you. i wanted to confirm 100%. is there any other way like can i make location service ON from code?

Comment: If it has been set to OFF from settings, you cant do it via code.

Answer (score 0):

This alert only shows the first time you try to get to location data through  the CLLocationManager (or MapKit). After that, it will not appear anymore. You can check for whether the user is able to authorise your app (he might be under parental control, in which case he cannot), and if he is able, then you can check for whether he has not done so, or if he has done, what the decision was.

[See:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/authorizationStatus)

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]
```

it is impossible NOT to show the alert on first try to access the locationamanger, this is something the framework will do (even out of your apps process). Also, this has changed a little in iOS 8, I suggest you also read up on what changed, as to avoid surprises (for your users).

Comment: Yes, you can use MKMapView and set a bool on it to show the user location on it. But this will also show that alert.